# Errors when installing pyinstaller

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

After punching in

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

I get a ton of warnings and these two errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyinstaller (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyinstaller
```

Every single warning just says

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pyinstaller/
```

Comment: do this pip install pyinstaller==4.1

Comment: @SachinRajput Still didn't work

Comment: did it still showed that no matching distribution found